# c++ Grpc::CompletionQueue construction speed is around 14k?

Tags: c++, grpc

In async-grpc,I try to create a new grpc::completionqueue with every connection.
Then,i find a problem.The construction speed of cq does not seem to be fast.

```
//It test with folly::benchmark
BENCHMARK(CompletionQueue){
    grpc::CompletionQueue cq;
}

BENCHMARK(folly_mpmcqueue){
    folly::MPMCQueue<int> cq;
}

BENCHMARK(std_queue){
    std::queue<int> cq;
}
```

the result is:

```
============================================================================
test.cpp                                        relative  time/iter  iters/s
============================================================================
CompletionQueue                                             63.99us   15.63K
folly_mpmcqueue                                             67.12ns   14.90M
std_queue                                                  220.97ns    4.53M
============================================================================
```

Cq does not seem to be free to construct and destruct.
So should I reuse them instead of creating a new one for each connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, completion queues can be reused. They are not tied to a single connection or call.